# asynchronous data with mysql php?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I do have a code which shows number of data in database. I want to send this data to browser in real time or in between couple of seconds using ajax or any other method...

My code:

```
$db = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password) or die("Could not connect.");
mysql_select_db($databse_name,$db)or die(mysql_error()); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table")or die(mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo "$num_rows\n";
```

Comment: Do some research on AJAX, write some code, and if you have problems with the code, THEN ask a question.

Comment: I am not at all familiar with Ajax...

Comment: @matthew Then learn it. You need to be more self sufficient if you want to succeed as a programmer. Otherwise you're just going to hit the endless cycle of relying on others for answers all the time, and you won't grow at all.

Comment: @mathew - a year ago you asked another question regarding AJAX and got a great answer with some links to Ajax resources.  I would suggest you check those out first to get a better feel for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery and that php code is in a file called your_code.php, you could do something like this:

```
$('#my_button').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "your_code.php",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#my_div').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but if i dont want use button send straight to browser then how does do this?? I am not familiar with Ajax or javascript